# Application of limits on individual terms

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, soft-question

While evaluating limits, when (and when not) can I apply limits to the individual terms of an expression?

Comment: Sometimes you can, sometimes you can't.  Obvious examples of when not to do include: $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac xx,\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n,\quad\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x$$

Comment: Most of the limit laws *assume* that certain limits exist (or exist and are nonzero, or ...).  If those assumptions are satisfied, then you can apply the limit laws.  If not, you might not be able to apply the limit laws.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: You can, whenever there is a law for limits which justifies it. Otherwise not.

For example, if you know that $f(x)\to A$ and $g(x) \to B$ as $x \to a$, then there's a limit law which allows you to conclude that $f(x)+g(x) \to A+B$ as $x \to a$ (provided that $A$ and $B$ are real numbers, *not* $\infty$ or $-\infty$, and – if one wants to be really precise – that $a$ is a limit point of the domain of definition of $f+g$).

Laws like this are listed (and proved, hopefully) in virtually every calculus textbook, and can also be found online. (Google “limit laws” or something like that.)

So just look up what these rules are. If you're in a situation where none of the rules apply (for example, if you have $f(x)+g(x)$ where $f(x) \to \infty$ and $g(x) \to -\infty$), you must try to rewrite the expression into some other form where you *can* apply some rule.

Comment: So basically whenever the individual terms approach some finite value?

Comment: @InternetGuy: More or less, except that the finite value *zero* can be problematic. (For example, there's no rule for the case $f(x)/g(x)$ where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both tend to zero.)